# In JavaFX how do I move a sprite across the screen?

Tags: animation, javafx, sprite, translation, game-loop

I'm new to JavaFX and am trying to write a game where an animated 2D character walks across the screen (for example like the original Legend of Zelda game). I had done this in Swing, by creating my own Sprite class and overriding the paintComponent() method in Swing, and putting my own  g2d.drawImage(...); call in there, where it would copy the correct subframe from a Sprite to the correct x,y destination in a JPanel, thus achieving the movement of an animated (walking) 2D image across the screen.

How can I do this in JavaFX? I found this excellent example on how to create a sprite:
http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-sprite-animation-with-javafx/
in JavaFX, but how do I do the PaintComponent and drawImage(...) parts? Does JavaFX have an equivalent method to PaintComponent where everything is redrawn?
I tried calling the primaryStage.show(); method, but that didn't work.

I guess I'm not clear on how exactly to set up my master game loop, where a refresh is triggered and an image is painted on the scene at a different x,y location?

What's the JavaFX equivalent to the drawImage(...) method? this method allows me to copy a part of a source image into a destination scene at any given x,y offset. That is how I achieved moving an animated sprite on screen in Swing.

Best Regards,

Zareh

Comment: Very basic demo for [moving a character round a screen](http://www.coderanch.com/t/626468/JavaFX/java/Key-Combinations) based on an [AnimationTimer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! I ran the code and it worked flawlessly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your question is too much to be covered on SO. However I created a simple "engine" for you to start with. It's general purpose, so also suited for your needs.

The main class with the game loop where the game is loaded, input is checked, sprites are moved, collision is checked, score is updated etc

```
public class Game extends Application {

    Random rnd = new Random();

    Pane playfieldLayer;
    Pane scoreLayer;

    Image playerImage;
    Image enemyImage;

    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<>();

    Text collisionText = new Text();
    boolean collision = false;

    Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Group root = new Group();

        // create layers
        playfieldLayer = new Pane();
        scoreLayer = new Pane();

        root.getChildren().add( playfieldLayer);
        root.getChildren().add( scoreLayer);

        scene = new Scene( root, Settings.SCENE_WIDTH, Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT);

        primaryStage.setScene( scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        loadGame();

        createScoreLayer();
        createPlayers();

        AnimationTimer gameLoop = new AnimationTimer() {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                // player input
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.processInput());

                // add random enemies
                spawnEnemies( true);

                // movement
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.move());
                enemies.forEach(sprite -> sprite.move());

                // check collisions
                checkCollisions();

                // update sprites in scene
                players.forEach(sprite -> sprite.updateUI());
                enemies.forEach(sprite -> sprite.updateUI());

                // check if sprite can be removed
                enemies.forEach(sprite -> sprite.checkRemovability());

                // remove removables from list, layer, etc
                removeSprites( enemies);

                // update score, health, etc
                updateScore();
            }

        };
        gameLoop.start();

    }

    private void loadGame() {
        playerImage = new Image( getClass().getResource("player.png").toExternalForm());
        enemyImage = new Image( getClass().getResource("enemy.png").toExternalForm());
    }

    private void createScoreLayer() {


        collisionText.setFont( Font.font( null, FontWeight.BOLD, 64));
        collisionText.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        collisionText.setFill(Color.RED);

        scoreLayer.getChildren().add( collisionText);

        // TODO: quick-hack to ensure the text is centered; usually you don't have that; instead you have a health bar on top
        collisionText.setText("Collision");
        double x = (Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - collisionText.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth()) / 2;
        double y = (Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT - collisionText.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight()) / 2;
        collisionText.relocate(x, y);
        collisionText.setText("");

        collisionText.setBoundsType(TextBoundsType.VISUAL);


    }
    private void createPlayers() {

        // player input
        Input input = new Input( scene);

        // register input listeners
        input.addListeners(); // TODO: remove listeners on game over

        Image image = playerImage;

        // center horizontally, position at 70% vertically
        double x = (Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - image.getWidth()) / 2.0;
        double y = Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT * 0.7;

        // create player
        Player player = new Player(playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, 0, 0, Settings.PLAYER_SHIP_HEALTH, 0, Settings.PLAYER_SHIP_SPEED, input);

        // register player
        players.add( player);

    }

    private void spawnEnemies( boolean random) {

        if( random && rnd.nextInt(Settings.ENEMY_SPAWN_RANDOMNESS) != 0) {
            return;
        }

        // image
        Image image = enemyImage;

        // random speed
        double speed = rnd.nextDouble() * 1.0 + 2.0;

        // x position range: enemy is always fully inside the screen, no part of it is outside
        // y position: right on top of the view, so that it becomes visible with the next game iteration
        double x = rnd.nextDouble() * (Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - image.getWidth());
        double y = -image.getHeight();

        // create a sprite
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy( playfieldLayer, image, x, y, 0, 0, speed, 0, 1,1);

        // manage sprite
        enemies.add( enemy);

    }

    private void removeSprites(  List<? extends SpriteBase> spriteList) {
        Iterator<? extends SpriteBase> iter = spriteList.iterator();
        while( iter.hasNext()) {
            SpriteBase sprite = iter.next();

            if( sprite.isRemovable()) {

                // remove from layer
                sprite.removeFromLayer();

                // remove from list
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkCollisions() {

        collision = false;

        for( Player player: players) {
            for( Enemy enemy: enemies) {
                if( player.collidesWith(enemy)) {
                    collision = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateScore() {
        if( collision) {
            collisionText.setText("Collision");
        } else {
            collisionText.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

A base class for sprites which includes common methods like movement, etc

```
public abstract class SpriteBase {

    Image image;
    ImageView imageView;

    Pane layer;

    double x;
    double y;
    double r;

    double dx;
    double dy;
    double dr;

    double health;
    double damage;

    boolean removable = false;

    double w;
    double h;

    boolean canMove = true;

    public SpriteBase(Pane layer, Image image, double x, double y, double r, double dx, double dy, double dr, double health, double damage) {

        this.layer = layer;
        this.image = image;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
        this.dr = dr;

        this.health = health;
        this.damage = damage;

        this.imageView = new ImageView(image);
        this.imageView.relocate(x, y);
        this.imageView.setRotate(r);

        this.w = image.getWidth(); // imageView.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
        this.h = image.getHeight(); // imageView.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();

        addToLayer();

    }

    public void addToLayer() {
        this.layer.getChildren().add(this.imageView);
    }

    public void removeFromLayer() {
        this.layer.getChildren().remove(this.imageView);
    }

    public Pane getLayer() {
        return layer;
    }

    public void setLayer(Pane layer) {
        this.layer = layer;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(double r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public double getDx() {
        return dx;
    }

    public void setDx(double dx) {
        this.dx = dx;
    }

    public double getDy() {
        return dy;
    }

    public void setDy(double dy) {
        this.dy = dy;
    }

    public double getDr() {
        return dr;
    }

    public void setDr(double dr) {
        this.dr = dr;
    }

    public double getHealth() {
        return health;
    }

    public double getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }

    public void setDamage(double damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public void setHealth(double health) {
        this.health = health;
    }

    public boolean isRemovable() {
        return removable;
    }

    public void setRemovable(boolean removable) {
        this.removable = removable;
    }

    public void move() {

        if( !canMove)
            return;

        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        r += dr;

    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return Double.compare(health, 0) > 0;
    }

    public ImageView getView() {
        return imageView;
    }

    public void updateUI() {

        imageView.relocate(x, y);
        imageView.setRotate(r);

    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return w;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return h;
    }

    public double getCenterX() {
        return x + w * 0.5;
    }

    public double getCenterY() {
        return y + h * 0.5;
    }

    // TODO: per-pixel-collision
    public boolean collidesWith( SpriteBase otherSprite) {

        return ( otherSprite.x + otherSprite.w >= x && otherSprite.y + otherSprite.h >= y && otherSprite.x <= x + w && otherSprite.y <= y + h);

    }

    /**
     * Reduce health by the amount of damage that the given sprite can inflict
     * @param sprite
     */
    public void getDamagedBy( SpriteBase sprite) {
        health -= sprite.getDamage();
    }

    /**
     * Set health to 0
     */
    public void kill() {
        setHealth( 0);
    }

    /**
     * Set flag that the sprite can be removed from the UI.
     */
    public void remove() {
        setRemovable(true);
    }

    /**
     * Set flag that the sprite can't move anymore.
     */
    public void stopMovement() {
        this.canMove = false;
    }

    public abstract void checkRemovability();

}
```

Subclasses of the sprite class like player ...

```
public class Player extends SpriteBase {

    double playerShipMinX;
    double playerShipMaxX;
    double playerShipMinY;
    double playerShipMaxY;

    Input input;

    double speed;

    public Player(Pane layer, Image image, double x, double y, double r, double dx, double dy, double dr, double health, double damage, double speed, Input input) {

        super(layer, image, x, y, r, dx, dy, dr, health, damage);

        this.speed = speed;
        this.input = input;

        init();
    }


    private void init() {

        // calculate movement bounds of the player ship
        // allow half of the ship to be outside of the screen 
        playerShipMinX = 0 - image.getWidth() / 2.0;
        playerShipMaxX = Settings.SCENE_WIDTH - image.getWidth() / 2.0;
        playerShipMinY = 0 - image.getHeight() / 2.0;
        playerShipMaxY = Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT -image.getHeight() / 2.0;

    }

    public void processInput() {

        // ------------------------------------
        // movement
        // ------------------------------------

        // vertical direction
        if( input.isMoveUp()) {
            dy = -speed;
        } else if( input.isMoveDown()) {
            dy = speed;
        } else {
            dy = 0d;
        }

        // horizontal direction
        if( input.isMoveLeft()) {
            dx = -speed;
        } else if( input.isMoveRight()) {
            dx = speed;
        } else {
            dx = 0d;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void move() {

        super.move();

        // ensure the ship can't move outside of the screen
        checkBounds();


    }

    private void checkBounds() {

        // vertical
        if( Double.compare( y, playerShipMinY) < 0) {
            y = playerShipMinY;
        } else if( Double.compare(y, playerShipMaxY) > 0) {
            y = playerShipMaxY;
        }

        // horizontal
        if( Double.compare( x, playerShipMinX) < 0) {
            x = playerShipMinX;
        } else if( Double.compare(x, playerShipMaxX) > 0) {
            x = playerShipMaxX;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void checkRemovability() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

... and enemies

```
public class Enemy extends SpriteBase {

    public Enemy(Pane layer, Image image, double x, double y, double r, double dx, double dy, double dr, double health, double damage) {
        super(layer, image, x, y, r, dx, dy, dr, health, damage);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkRemovability() {

        if( Double.compare( getY(), Settings.SCENE_HEIGHT) > 0) {
            setRemovable(true);
        }


    }
}
```

You also need an input mechanism to control the player sprite

```
public class Input {

    /**
     * Bitset which registers if any {@link KeyCode} keeps being pressed or if it is released.
     */
    private BitSet keyboardBitSet = new BitSet();

    // -------------------------------------------------
    // default key codes
    // will vary when you let the user customize the key codes or when you add support for a 2nd player
    // -------------------------------------------------

    private KeyCode upKey = KeyCode.UP;
    private KeyCode downKey = KeyCode.DOWN;
    private KeyCode leftKey = KeyCode.LEFT;
    private KeyCode rightKey = KeyCode.RIGHT;
    private KeyCode primaryWeaponKey = KeyCode.SPACE;
    private KeyCode secondaryWeaponKey = KeyCode.CONTROL;

    Scene scene;

    public Input( Scene scene) {
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public void addListeners() {

        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyPressedEventHandler);
        scene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyReleasedEventHandler);

    }

    public void removeListeners() {

        scene.removeEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyPressedEventHandler);
        scene.removeEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, keyReleasedEventHandler);

    }

    /**
     * "Key Pressed" handler for all input events: register pressed key in the bitset
     */
    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyPressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            // register key down
            keyboardBitSet.set(event.getCode().ordinal(), true);

        }
    };

    /**
     * "Key Released" handler for all input events: unregister released key in the bitset
     */
    private EventHandler<KeyEvent> keyReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {

            // register key up
            keyboardBitSet.set(event.getCode().ordinal(), false);

        }
    };


    // -------------------------------------------------
    // Evaluate bitset of pressed keys and return the player input.
    // If direction and its opposite direction are pressed simultaneously, then the direction isn't handled.
    // -------------------------------------------------

    public boolean isMoveUp() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( upKey.ordinal()) && !keyboardBitSet.get( downKey.ordinal());
    }

    public boolean isMoveDown() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( downKey.ordinal()) && !keyboardBitSet.get( upKey.ordinal());
    }

    public boolean isMoveLeft() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( leftKey.ordinal()) && !keyboardBitSet.get( rightKey.ordinal());  
    }

    public boolean isMoveRight() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( rightKey.ordinal()) && !keyboardBitSet.get( leftKey.ordinal());
    }

    public boolean isFirePrimaryWeapon() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( primaryWeaponKey.ordinal());
    }

    public boolean isFireSecondaryWeapon() {
        return keyboardBitSet.get( secondaryWeaponKey.ordinal());
    }

}
```

And some global settings

```
public class Settings {

    public static double SCENE_WIDTH = 400;
    public static double SCENE_HEIGHT = 800;

    public static double PLAYER_SHIP_SPEED = 4.0;
    public static double PLAYER_SHIP_HEALTH = 100.0;

    public static double PLAYER_MISSILE_SPEED = 4.0;
    public static double PLAYER_MISSILE_HEALTH = 200.0;

    public static int ENEMY_SPAWN_RANDOMNESS = 100;

}
```

You can use any image for the sprites. I took mine from Wikipedia:

player.png

[image]

enemy.png

[image]

If you put it all into a game package, you can start the Game.java. It'll give you a controllable smiley with zombie smilies that scroll down. You have to evade them. I left the images without transparency for you so that you'll notice that I use a simple rectangle collision detection. You'll probably go for a per-pixel-collision detection.

It looks like this:

[image]

I don't claim this to be *the* solution, it's just *a* solution. For example you'd have to limit the animation timer. Or you may want to set the movement per seconds instead of per frame, etc.

If you want more information, feel free to check out my blog in which I discover myself [How to create a 2D Shoot'em'up with JavaFX](http://wecode4fun.blogspot.co.at/2015/01/chapter-2-from-prototype-to-game-its.html). There you'll also find e. g. how to add animated sprites (I also learned that from the link you posted), a scrolling background, a cloud layer on top of the other layers, etc. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for that detailed answer! I definitely get the idea from looking at your code. Much appreciated.