# Binding property dont work

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a very simple game in JavaFX. I have two objects for representing player:

1. player - instance of Player class
2. playerObj - instance of Rectangle class, used for representating player on the map

Now I implemented basic functions for player movement like goUp, goLeft etc. These all change properties X and Y in player class (these are DoubleProperty type). Now I want to make it so every change of player's X and Y property will reflect in playerObj so I used property binding like this:

```
 playerObj.yProperty().bind(player.yProperty());
```

But when I invoke the goUp() method, the "y property" in player object will change, but "y property" in playerObj object won't change. So:

```
    pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        switch(e.getCode()) {
            case UP:
                player.goUp();
                System.out.println("player Y property: "+player.yProperty().getValue());
                System.out.println("playerObj Y property: "+playerObj.yProperty().getValue());
                break;
        }
    });
```

Will result in this (after invoking goUp() method 3 times):

```
player Y property: 245.0
playerObj Y property: 250.0
player Y property: 240.0
playerObj Y property: 250.0
player Y property: 235.0
playerObj Y property: 250.0
```

Why didn't the playerObj Y property change too when I binded it with player Y property?

EDIT: Full code (removed irrelevant parts)

Player.java

```
public class Player {

    private DoubleProperty x;
    private DoubleProperty y;
    private Scene scene;

    public Player(Scene scene) {
        this(DEFAULT_NAME, DEFAULT_COLOR, scene);
    }

    public Player(String name, Color color, Scene scene) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.color = color;
        this.scene = scene;
    }

    public Rectangle drawPlayer() {
        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(getX(),getY(),SIZE_OF_PLAYER,SIZE_OF_PLAYER);
        player.setFill(color);
        return player;
    }

    public Player goUp() {
        if(getY() != 0 && getY() != scene.getHeight()) {
           setY(yProperty().subtract(5).getValue());
       }
    }


    public DoubleProperty xProperty() {
        return x;
    }

    public DoubleProperty yProperty() {
        return y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x.getValue();
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = new SimpleDoubleProperty(x);
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y.getValue();
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = new SimpleDoubleProperty(y);
    }
}
```

Game.java

```
public class Game extends Application {

    private Scene scene;
    private Player player;
    private Rectangle playerObj;
    private Pane pane;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        pane = new Pane();
        scene = new Scene(pane,500,500);
        player = new Player(scene);

        player.setX(scene.getWidth() / 2);
        player.setY(scene.getHeight() / 2);
        playerObj = player.drawPlayer();
        pane.getChildren().add(playerObj);
        playerObj.yProperty().bind(player.yProperty());

        pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            switch(e.getCode()) {
                case LEFT:
                    player.goLeft();
                    break;
                case UP:
                    player.goUp();
                    System.out.println("player Y property: "+player.yProperty().getValue());
                    System.out.println("playerObj Y property: "+playerObj.yProperty().getValue());
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    player.goRight();
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    player.goDown();
            }
        });

        pane.requestFocus();

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: All the code you've posted looks correct and should behave the way you want; so there are probably errors elsewhere in your code that prevent it working. Can you create a [simple, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it?

Comment: See also: [How to write a KeyListener for JavaFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962395/how-to-write-a-keylistener-for-javafx).

Comment: @James_D i extended the OP with full code (removed only parts that have nothing to do with this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` properties in the `Player` class are incorrectly implemented.

When you call `player.setY(...)` you create a *new* `DoubleProperty`:

```
public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = new SimpleDoubleProperty(y);
}
```

and of course this is not the property to which your node was earlier bound. So it's value is not reflected in the node.

You need

```
public void setY(double y) {
    this.y.set(y);
}
```

and similarly for `setX(...)`.