# javafx 8 - count number of clicks and keys pressed

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am developing sth like a time tracker and I need to count how many times mouse or keyboard was used during a certain time frame. I don't mean clicks on interface but clicks and key events in common. How can I intercept it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962395/how-to-write-a-keylistener-for-javafx

Comment: Thanks, but I`m not sure it will work for any corner of desktop. For example, I minimize my app and it will still record clicks. I guess it won't work but I will try, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

First we need to create listener class

```
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseInputListener;

public class NativeMouseListener implements NativeMouseInputListener {
    public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Mosue Clicked: " + e.getClickCount());
    }

    public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("Mosue Pressed: " + e.getButton());
    }

    public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("Mosue Released: " + e.getButton());
    }

    public void nativeMouseMoved(NativeMouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("Mosue Moved: " + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
    }

    public void nativeMouseDragged(NativeMouseEvent e) {
        //System.out.println("Mosue Dragged: " + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
    }
}
```

Then, do the following in your code:

```
try {
    GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
}
catch (NativeHookException ex) {
    System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    System.exit(1);
}

GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(new NativeMouseListener());
```

You can take jnative jar from there:

```
https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/releases/
```

But I'm not sure will it work for mac or not.