# Scene builder event handler ( Key listener)

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

hello guys i have a problem, i am using eclipse , javafx and scene builder
i want to move the ellipse( the circle) when i use arrow ( right left....)
here is my code ( i tried like 10 things but nothing seems to work ) this is the last think i tried if any one can help thank :)

This is my Main class :

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
   public class Main extends Application {
@Override
   public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/Sample.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new SampleController());
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

This is my controller class :

```
 package application;
 import javafx.fxml.FXML;
 import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
 import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
 public class SampleController {
 @FXML
 private Ellipse Test;
@FXML
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key){
    if(key.getCode().isArrowKey()){
      System.out.println("rlrlrl");
    }}}
```

My FXML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.Double?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Stop?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<Pane onKeyPressed="#keyPressed" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" 
minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"  prefHeight="600.0" 
prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
  <Polygon fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="507.0" layoutY="587.0" rotate="180.0" 
 stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE">
    <points>
      <Double fx:value="-50.0" />
      <Double fx:value="40.0" />
      <Double fx:value="50.0" />
      <Double fx:value="40.0" />
      <Double fx:value="0.0" />
      <Double fx:value="-60.0" />
    </points>
  </Polygon>
  <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" height="200.0" layoutX="-3.0" layoutY="577.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="809.0">
     <fill>
        <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="1.0">
           <stops>
              <Stop color="#4c6b33" />
              <Stop color="WHITE" offset="1.0" />
           </stops>
        </LinearGradient>
     </fill>
  </Rectangle>
  <Ellipse fx:id="Test"  fill="DODGERBLUE" layoutX="60.0" layoutY="558.0"  
  radiusX="23.0" radiusY="19.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" />
  </children>
  </Pane>
```

i tried everything on every forums ; (the switch statement,changing my main,changing on the fxml but none worked)

Comment: possible duplication https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37472273/detect-single-key-press-in-javafx?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: i already seen this one and its dont talk about FXML and scene builder its just about JavaFx , thanks for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

**you have to use scene instead Pane for detecting keypressed**

```
    @Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/Sample.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
        String codeString = event.getCode().toString();
        if (event.getCode().isArrowKey()) {
            System.out.println("rlrlrl");
        }
    });
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: even if i wanna just move the circle ? i use the scene ?

Comment: I believe you are trying to detect key pressed for whole scene .So,using scene to detect the keypresses is an appropriate solution.

Comment: cant i write the code in other classe and use it in the main like i did in the exemple ?

Answer (score 0):

In code

```
  FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/Sample.fxml"));
  loader.setController(new SampleController());
  primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
  primaryStage.show()
```

Change this to

```
   FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/Sample.fxml"));
   loader.setController(new SampleController());
   Pane root = loader.load(); 
   Scene scene = new Scene(root)
   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show()
   scene.getRoot().requestFocus(); // important
```

Comment: omg thanks its worked i will try to do more codes to see if all work good but can u tell me the last one where you tell its important its used for what ?

Comment: @AimenBadaoui statement `scene.getRoot().requestFocus()` is important because root Pane wont receive key event until it has focus. This statement simply request's focus so that root pane can listen for keyevents