# Graphics Context will only draw in one thread

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a game of snake, but whenever I try to update my canvas in the `draw()` method, the new snake won't draw. It draws in the `run` thread. I have tried a bunch of different things, but I can't seem to get it working.

**Imports:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.canvas.*;
```

**Actual class:**

```
public class Snake extends Application implements Runnable
{
    //Snake parts and locations
    boolean dead;
    int headX=0;
    int headY=0;
    // for the game
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene snakeG = new Scene(root, 550, 550,Color.BLACK);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(550,550);
    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    //Start Game
    VBox newGame = new VBox(3);
    Scene startC = new Scene(newGame, 200, 200);
    Label info = new Label("Snake Game \nCreated by: Austin");
    Label rules = new Label("Rules\n1.) If you hit the edge you die\n2.) If you touch your snake you die\n3.)Collect fruit to increase your snakes size");
    Button startBut = new Button("Start Game");
    Stage startS;

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start ( Stage primaryStage )throws Exception
    {
        startS=primaryStage;
        startS.setTitle("Snake");
        newGame.getChildren().addAll(info,rules,startBut);
        newGame.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        startS.setScene(startC);
        startS.show();

        startBut.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            startGame();
        });
    }

    public void startGame()
    {
        System.out.println("Success");
        headX=275;
        headY=275;
        dead = false;
        gc.clearRect(0,0,800,800);
        startS.setScene(snakeG);
        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gc.fillRect(headX,headY,10,10);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);
        (new Thread ( new Snake())).start();    
    }

    public void run()
    {
        draw(); 
    }

    // draws the snake
    public void draw()
    {
        System.out.println("DRAW STARTED");
        gc.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        gc.fillRect(50,50,10,10);   
    }
}
```

If you know of a better way to draw graphics in JavaFX, please tell me. This is the only way I could find for what I am doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some problems with your approach.

1. You don't need your own thread.
2. You can only modify the active scene graph (including a canvas) using the JavaFX Thread.  Read the [JavaFX concurrency documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm):

   > The JavaFX scene graph, which represents the graphical user interface of a JavaFX application, is not thread-safe and can only be accessed and modified from the UI thread also known as the JavaFX Application thread.
3. Your main application class should not implement `Runnable`.

Some suggestions:

1. You may find it easier to use `SceneGraph` nodes for your game objects rather than a `Canvas`, but either should work.
2. You can implement your [game loop](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html) using an [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) as [demoed here](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html).
3. Here is a sample of [using an AnimationTimer for display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962395/how-to-write-a-keylistener-for-javafx).

Comment: I've never had a problem using `GraphicsContext2d` on it's own thread.  I think all those drawing operations can be called off the UI thread.  I also looked at the source and there's no check for `Platform.isFxApplicationThread()`

Comment: GraphicsContext Javadoc clearly states __Each call pushes the necessary
parameters onto the buffer
where they will be later
rendered onto the image of
the Canvas node by the
rendering thread at the end of
a pulse.__ Thus, it is completely thread independent.

Comment: @MouseEvent That does not make it thread safe. There is no synchronization on the buffer, so if you modify it from a background thread you run all sorts of risks: you may change the buffer while the FX Application Thread is rendering a pulse, meaning that the FX Application Thread may see different, potentially inconsistent, states of the buffer during a single pulse. (There are other risks too, such as liveness, etc.)

Comment: @brian Not every operation that must be performed on the FX Application Thread actually checks that it is on the correct thread. For some operations the performance overhead of the check is prohibitive - the JavaFX team probably thought this was the case with canvas operations. Just because it happens to work on your particular system does not make it safe: the documentation quoted in this answer is very clear. It is an error to execute code that modifies the state of the scene graph from any thread exception the FX Application Thread.

Comment: @James_D I understand the quote, I'm just not sure that drawing to the canvas qualifies as modifying the scene graph.  The canvas also doesn't get a css layout pass, maybe that's why I never get errors.

Comment: @brian It's not thread safe, period. Operations on the graphics context modify the state of the graphics context, which is part of the state of the canvas, which is part of the scene graph.

Comment: @James_D You're right.  After stress testing I sometimes get `.NullPointerException
 at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.synchronizeSceneNodes(Scene.java:2289)`  But that's with many canvases and threads.  `Platform.runLater()` will run the test perfectly.  However, in my use case I will still have too many `runLater()`s and my program will crash.

Comment: One further clarification may be helpfull in some cases. It IS allowed to write graphics command to a GraphicsContext of a canvas from ANY thread as long as the canvas is not yet attached to the scene graph. In this way you can prepare a canvas on some thread without slowing down the JavaFX application thread. The actual rendering will then be delayed until you attach the canvas to the scene graph.