# Two threads calling the same keyEvents method

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, netbeans, thread-safety

I have a thread for player1 keyEvents which works, but when I add another thread for player2 keyevents, only the player2 keypresses are registered. Is it an issue with the threads or with the keyEvents() method? I don't know where to go next with this.

```
    //keyEvents thread for player 1
    AnimationTimer player1_timer = new AnimationTimer(){
        @Override
        public void handle(long now){
            keyEvents(player1, 1);
        }
    };
    player1_timer.start();

    if(true){ //if I set this to false, player1 keyEvents are registered again.
        //keyEvents thread for player 2
        AnimationTimer player2_timer = new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle(long now){
                keyEvents(player2, 2);
            }
        };
        player2_timer.start();
    }

private void keyEvents(Unit player, int playerNumber){
    map.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e) -> {
        if(playerNumber == 1){
            if(null != e.getCode())switch (e.getCode()) {
                case LEFT:
                    player1.rotateLeft();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        if(playerNumber == 2){
            if(null != e.getCode())switch (e.getCode()) {
                case A:
                    player2.rotateLeft();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Updated Code:

```
//keyEvents thread for players
    AnimationTimer playerTimer = new AnimationTimer(){
        @Override
        public void handle(long now){
            keyEvents();
        }
    };
    playerTimer.start();
private void keyEvents(){
        Bullet bullet = new Bullet();
        map.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e) -> {
            if(null != e.getCode())switch (e.getCode()) {
                case A:
                    player2.rotateLeft();
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    player1.rotateLeft();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you should be calling `setOnKeyPressed` repeatedly, instead, you call it once when you setup the UI. When a key event occurs, you store the state (pressed/released) and check the state from the timers

Comment: Oh, and you probably don't want two timers, you probably only want one - since they'd both be triggered within the same thread anyway, it's not providing your with any additional benifit

Comment: @madprogrammer what happens if they both press A and LEFT at the same time though. Won't it just read one of them?

Comment: KeyEvents seems to set up an event listener so the last call will overwrite the first one.  Rather than call keyEvents from the timmer which reregisteres the listener, can you fire a key event instead that the listner would react to?

Comment: @Nils_e You will get two seperate events - the events are handled and managed by a single, event dispatching thread. You need to store the state some how, so when the timer triggers, you, can inspect the state and take appropriate actions. This is a very common concept. It should also allow you to decouple the input from the logic, as the logic should care about where the input is coming from (mouse/joystick/AI), only that changes to the state trigger some kind of action

Comment: @Nils_e So, essentially, [this example demonstrates the basic concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962395/how-to-write-a-keylistener-for-javafx)

Comment: @MadProgrammer your input actually helped me to fix the problem. I got rid of one thread and have only one KeyEvent e and depending on which key is pressed it will call the appropriate player functions! Ill add the code update on the bottom. Thank you! Write up an answer and I can mark it, if you like.

Comment: @Nils_e *"I got rid of one thread"*. Note that creating `AnimationTimer`s does not create any new *threads*. All `AnimationTimer`'s `handle()` methods are invoked on the FX Application Thread during a "pulse" (a rendering of the scene).

Comment: @MadProframmer updated the code so you can see it.

Comment: @James_D ooo ok, thanks for the knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is like only my second JavaFX program, so I'm sure there are a number of improvements that could be made.

You have to recognise that you're still only dealing with a single thread, JavaFX's Event Dispatching Thread.

The `AnimationTimer` and `EventHandler`s are all called within the context of this thread, so adding more of them isn't going to provide you with any additional benefit, and could actually be departmental.

Instead, you want to add a single handler for `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`.  In these handlers, you want to set the state of a given direction for a given player.

One of simplest ways to do this is through a `Set`, which you can `add` and `remove` a "key" object, which would represent the direction for a given player.

You would then use a single `AnimationTimer` to act as the "main loop" and which would, based on the state of the `Set`, make determinations about the direction that the player objects should be moved.

This is very common concept in game development, it's simple, but it also decouples the logic from the state, so that the state can be set through any means (mouse/joystick/AI/network) and the logic won't care.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelWriter;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.DOWN;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.SHIFT;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.UP;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    enum Direction {
        UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
    }

    private static final double W = 600, H = 400;

    private Image playerOneImage;
    private Node playerOneNode;

    private Image playerTwoImage;
    private Node playerTwoNode;

    private Set<Direction> playerOneDirection = new TreeSet<>();
    private Set<Direction> playerTwoDirection = new TreeSet<>();

    boolean running;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        playerOneImage = makePlayerOne();
        playerOneNode = new ImageView(playerOneImage);

        playerTwoImage = makePlayerTwo();
        playerTwoNode = new ImageView(playerTwoImage);

        Group dungeon = new Group(playerOneNode, playerTwoNode);

        movePlayerTo(playerOneNode, 0, 0);
        movePlayerTo(playerTwoNode, W - 12.5, H - 12.5);

        Scene scene = new Scene(dungeon, W, H, Color.FORESTGREEN);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                    case UP:
                        playerOneDirection.add(Direction.UP);
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        playerOneDirection.add(Direction.DOWN);
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        playerOneDirection.add(Direction.LEFT);
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        playerOneDirection.add(Direction.RIGHT);
                        break;
                    case W:
                        playerTwoDirection.add(Direction.UP);
                        break;
                    case S:
                        playerTwoDirection.add(Direction.DOWN);
                        break;
                    case A:
                        playerTwoDirection.add(Direction.LEFT);
                        break;
                    case D:
                        playerTwoDirection.add(Direction.RIGHT);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        scene.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                    case UP:
                        playerOneDirection.remove(Direction.UP);
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        playerOneDirection.remove(Direction.DOWN);
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        playerOneDirection.remove(Direction.LEFT);
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        playerOneDirection.remove(Direction.RIGHT);
                        break;
                    case W:
                        playerTwoDirection.remove(Direction.UP);
                        break;
                    case S:
                        playerTwoDirection.remove(Direction.DOWN);
                        break;
                    case A:
                        playerTwoDirection.remove(Direction.LEFT);
                        break;
                    case D:
                        playerTwoDirection.remove(Direction.RIGHT);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                movePlayer(playerOneNode, playerOneDirection);
                movePlayer(playerTwoNode, playerTwoDirection);
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    private void movePlayer(Node playerNode, Set<Direction> direction) {
        int dx = 0;
        int dy = 0;
        if (direction.contains(Direction.UP)) {
            dy -= 1;
        }
        if (direction.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
            dy += 1;
        }
        if (direction.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
            dx += 1;
        }
        if (direction.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
            dx -= 1;
        }
        if (running) {
            dx *= 3;
            dy *= 3;
        }
        if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) {
            return;
        }

        final double cx = playerNode.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() / 2;
        final double cy = playerNode.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2;

        double x = cx + playerNode.getLayoutX() + dx;
        double y = cy + playerNode.getLayoutY() + dy;

        movePlayerTo(playerNode, x, y);
    }

    private void movePlayerTo(Node playerNode, double x, double y) {
        final double cx = playerNode.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() / 2;
        final double cy = playerNode.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2;

        if (x - cx >= 0
                        && x + cx <= W
                        && y - cy >= 0
                        && y + cy <= H) {
            playerNode.relocate(x - cx, y - cy);
        }
    }

    protected Image makePlayerOne() {
        return makePlayer(Color.RED);
    }

    protected Image makePlayerTwo() {
        return makePlayer(Color.BLUE);
    }

    protected Image makePlayer(Color color) {
        WritableImage image = new WritableImage(25, 25);
        PixelWriter writer = image.getPixelWriter();
        for (int y = 0; y < 25; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 25; x++) {
                writer.setColor(x, y, color);
            }
        }
        return image;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this is really helpful. I wasn't expecting this at all. Thank you!