# JavaFX KeyCode for constant MINUS

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, java-9

I'm using Eclipse. I developed simple JavaFX calculator app, everything is working but keyevent for numpad MINUS and PLUS. Which is funny because every other numpad key is ok. Am I missing something?

```
public void onKeyPress(KeyEvent event) {
    KeyCode keyCode = event.getCode();
```

Just a piece of my code:

```
case PLUS:
    if (operation.getOperand() == 'x') {
        operation.add(Double.parseDouble("" + display.getText()), display);
        decimal.setDisable(false);
    } else {
        result.fire();
        operation.add(Double.parseDouble("" + display.getText()), display);
        decimal.setDisable(false);
    }
    break;
```

Just now i thought of debugging keycodes themselves while running the app. Added a simple console output of a keycode that is currently pressed, found out that constant for numpad plus and minus in not PLUS and MINUS but **ADD** and **SUBTRACT**. 
Thanks to all who took the time to answer me.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `KeyCode`? For me it is `ADD` and `SUBTRACT`. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html

Comment: Did you see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963104/4671908

Comment: I found that `KeyCode.ADD` and `KeyCode.SUBTRACT` work for me - numpad +/- keys

Comment: I also found that `KeyCode.MINUS` and `KeyCode.EQUALS` represent the -/+ next to the number keys along the top - but you'll need to inspect the `shift` state