# How to trigger an event in a JavaFX Application (Stage) when some keys are pressed on the KeyBoard?

Tags: javafx, keystroke

I'm trying to setup a backdoor on an application which I'm working on.

I want to load a new Window when the user presses "CTRL + ALT + F12".
This is what I have tried so far though it is terribly bad.

```
//packages
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;

//...
private void setupBackPass(){
        HashMap<KeyStroke, Action> actionMap = new HashMap<KeyStroke, Action>();
        KeyStroke key1 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.ALT, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
        actionMap.put(key1, new AbstractAction("action1") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Ctrl-ALT pressed: " +e);
            }
        });


        KeyboardFocusManager kfm = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        kfm.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
                KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(e);
                if(actionMap.containsKey(keyStroke)){
                final Action a = actionMap.get(keyStroke);
                final ActionEvent ae = new ActionEvent(e.getSource(), e.getID(), null);
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
                });

                return false;
                }
            });
        });


    }
```

Am not sure how to do it but I would like it that if the keys are pressed then a Super admin window should be opened.

Comment: How is this related to JavaFX? What packages do `EventQueue` and `KeyboardFocusManager` belong to?

Comment: here are the packages import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;

Comment: So this is AWT/Swing, not JavaFX, isn't it?

Comment: No it is javafx... but it just i can't figure out the right way to do it..

Comment: Explain how this is JavaFX if all the code is from AWT/Swing. Additionally, post a [mcve] that uses this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted, it looks like you are using *Swing* and **not** JavaFX. It also looks like you are trying to use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). As explained in that link, you need to modify both the *input map* and the *action map*. Also, you don't create an action map, you use the existing one. Again, that is explained in the page that I provided a link to.

Comment: It could be that they are embedding JavaFX and Swing into each other. I would suggest, in general, not to post guesses and wait until the question is made clear. The OP insists they are using JavaFX.

Comment: It's Javafx application not swing please.... It just happens that I don't know the right way to do it....

Comment: The code you posted is pure _Swing_. If it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck, does that mean it's not a duck?

Comment: Ok..... I will agree with you... But please may you let me know how to do it the JavaFX way

Comment: One way is to use a _key listener_. Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962395/how-to-write-a-keylistener-for-javafx) question will help.