# How do i check if a key is pressed or not on JavaFX key event

Tags: java, javafx

I have a question on the library JavaFX. And i want to check if an specific key is pressed or not as the title said. For example:

```
if (event.getCode == KeyCode.W) {
    isPressed = true;
} else {
    isPressed = false;
}
```

Something like that, but i want to set that `isPressed` is `false` no only when another key is pressed but when the key itself is released. How can i do that?

Comment: use a handler for the keyPressed type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a KeyListener for JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962395/how-to-write-a-keylistener-for-javafx)

Comment: My question is solved. Thanks.