# How to setup a KeyListener that listens to the Windows key in JavaFX without the OS using that keypress as an action?

Tags: javafx, keylistener, javafx-11, windows-key

How do I setup a `KeyListener` that listens to the `Windows key` in JavaFX without the OS using that keypress as an action? Here is my code so far, but my OS just recognizes the keypress as an input and the program does not recognize it because of that:

```java
package org.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class App extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("app.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(keyEvent -> System.out.println(keyEvent.getCode()));

        stage.setTitle("App");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a KeyListener for JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962395/how-to-write-a-keylistener-for-javafx)

Comment: Yes, it kinda does. But how do I only use the Windows key for my program and not as an input for the OS?

Comment: If you post code you tried to use with information how it misbehaves then somebody may spot where is the issue.

Comment: I added my code...