# Is there any way to add a Delay on KeyEvent or something

Tags: javafx

I write a simple Snake Game but there is a tiny little bug on it. When I press the up and left arrows quickly (this might happened other directions too) snake's head crashes on the body and game will over... Basically snake's head don't get the first direction and ultimately takes the second direction I pressed. Is there any solution for it? Here is the my whole code...

```
public class Main extends Application {

int sceneX = 600;
int sceneY = 400;
int size = 10;
int currentDirection;
int score = 0;
int highScore = 0;
double animationRate = 1.00;
boolean gameOver = false;
ArrayList <Rectangle> snake = new ArrayList<>();
Rectangle food = new Rectangle(size-1, size-1, Color.BLUE);
Rectangle dummy;
Pane pane;
Timeline timeline;
Text scoreBoard;
Text highScoreBoard = new Text(sceneX-100, -13, "High Score: "+highScore);
Button newGame = new Button("New Game");    

private static final int RIGHT = 0;
private static final int LEFT = 1;
private static final int UP = 2;
private static final int DOWN = 3;    

public Node sceneGraph() {
    pane = new Pane();
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:gray;");
    pane.setPrefSize(sceneX, sceneY);
    createSnake();
    createFood();
    createDummy();
    pane.getChildren().add(food);
    pane.getChildren().add(highScoreBoard);
    return pane;        
}

private void run() {
    if (gameOver) {
        Text gameOver = new Text(sceneX/5.5, sceneY/2, "GAME OVER");
        gameOver.setFill(Color.RED);
        gameOver.setFont(Font.font(STYLESHEET_CASPIAN, 70));
        pane.getChildren().add(gameOver);
        pane.getChildren().removeAll(snake.get(0), snake.get(1));
        newGame.setLayoutX((sceneX/5.5)+150);
        newGame.setLayoutY((sceneY/2)+10);  
        newGame.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                newGame();
            }
        });     
        pane.getChildren().add(newGame);
        timeline.stop();
        highScore();
    }
    for (int i = snake.size()-1; i>=1; i--) {
        snake.get(i).setLayoutX(snake.get(i-1).getLayoutX());
        snake.get(i).setLayoutY(snake.get(i-1).getLayoutY());
    }   
            
    eatFood();

    switch (currentDirection) {
    case RIGHT:
        snake.get(0).setLayoutX(snake.get(0).getLayoutX()+size);
        break;
    case LEFT:
        snake.get(0).setLayoutX(snake.get(0).getLayoutX()-size);
        break;
    case UP:
        snake.get(0).setLayoutY(snake.get(0).getLayoutY()-size);
        break;
    case DOWN:
        snake.get(0).setLayoutY(snake.get(0).getLayoutY()+size);
        break;
}
    gameOver();
    selfDestruct();
}

private void createSnake() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        dummy = new Rectangle(size-1, size-1, Color.BLACK);
        // Position the shapes in the Pane using the layoutX/Y properties.
        dummy.setLayoutX(100);
        dummy.setLayoutY(300);
        dummy.setArcHeight(size-5);
        dummy.setArcWidth(size-5);
        pane.getChildren().add(dummy);
        snake.add(dummy);
    }
}

private void createFood() {
    food.setLayoutX(Math.round(Math.random()*(sceneX-size)/size)*size);
    food.setLayoutY(Math.round(Math.random()*(sceneY-size)/size)*size);
    food.setArcHeight(5);
    food.setArcWidth(5);
}

private void createDummy() {
    dummy = new Rectangle(size-1, size-1, Color.BLACK);
    dummy.setLayoutX(-100);
    dummy.setLayoutY(-100);
    dummy.setArcHeight(size-5);
    dummy.setArcWidth(size-5);
    pane.getChildren().add(dummy);
}       

private void eatFood() {
    if (snake.get(0).getLayoutX() == food.getLayoutX() && snake.get(0).getLayoutY() == food.getLayoutY()) {
        createFood();
        snake.add(dummy);
        createDummy();
        score +=5;
        scoreBoard.setText("Score: "+score);            
        animationRate += 0.05;
        timeline.setRate(animationRate);
        timeline.play();
    }   
}   

private void gameOver() {
    if (snake.get(0).getLayoutX() < 0 || snake.get(0).getLayoutY() < 0 
            || snake.get(0).getLayoutX() >= (sceneX) || snake.get(0).getLayoutY() >= (sceneY)) {
        gameOver = true;
    }   
    
}

private void selfDestruct() {
    for (int i = 1; i< snake.size(); i++) {
        if (snake.get(0).getLayoutX() == snake.get(i).getLayoutX() && 
                snake.get(0).getLayoutY() == snake.get(i).getLayoutY()) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }
    
}

private void highScore() {
    if (highScore < score) {
        highScore = score;
    }
    highScoreBoard.setText("High Score: "+highScore);       
}


private void newGame() {
    gameOver = false;
    pane.getChildren().clear();
    snake = new ArrayList<>();
    createSnake();
    createFood();
    createDummy();
    pane.getChildren().add(food);
    pane.getChildren().add(highScoreBoard);
    currentDirection = RIGHT;
    score = 0;
    scoreBoard.setText("Score: "+score);            
    animationRate = 1;
    timeline.setRate(animationRate);
    timeline.play();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("SNAKE");
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    root.setHgap(10);
    root.setVgap(10);
    root.addRow(0, scoreBoard = new Text("Score: "+score));
    root.addRow(1, sceneGraph());
    Scene scene = new Scene (root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            KeyCode code = event.getCode();
            if (code == KeyCode.RIGHT || code == KeyCode.D) {
                
                
                if (currentDirection != LEFT) {
                    currentDirection = RIGHT;
                }
            } else if (code == KeyCode.LEFT || code == KeyCode.A) {
                if (currentDirection != RIGHT) {
                    currentDirection = LEFT;
                }
            } else if (code == KeyCode.UP || code == KeyCode.W) {
                if (currentDirection != DOWN) {
                    currentDirection = UP;
                }
            } else if (code == KeyCode.DOWN || code == KeyCode.S) {
                if (currentDirection != UP) {
                    currentDirection = DOWN;
                }
            }
        }
    });
            
    timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(130), e -> run()));
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.play();   

}
```

Comment: It sounds like the problem is you allow the snake to do a 180 in a single move. In your game model, during an update, check that the new direction is not the reverse of the current direction (e.g., if the snake is heading right, and the user tried to go left, simply do not accept that change in direction).

Comment: I actually doing exactly this (at least i think so) in the KeyEvent (if (currentDirection != LEFT)....). The problem is when i press the up and left keys quickly current direction changes quicker than the snake's head. In the end snake head goes directly to the left instead of going first up then left.

Comment: The problem is you store the new direction in `currentDirection`. Have your key handler update a different field, then in your `run()` method synchronize the current direction with the new direction.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at the "generic input handler sample" from [How to write a KeyListener for JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963104/1155209) and see if that might be applicable to your app.  The approach is similar to Slaw's suggested approach but can keep track of multiple simultaneous key presses.  To use this approach you would create a `applyInputToSnake(Set<KeyCode> activeKeys)` method invoked from an `update(long now, Set<KeyCode> activeKeys)` method which is triggered from an AnimationTimer.

Comment: Thank you guys i simply change the handler method and its solve my problem for now..`if (snake.get(0).getLayoutY()<snake.get(1).getLayoutY() || snake.get(0).getLayoutY()>snake.get(1).getLayoutY()) {
                        currentDirection = RIGHT;`