# JavaFX - Interaction between circle and rectangle

Tags: java, javafx

I want to know how I can make an interaction when rectangle collapses with a circle . Like some kind of action that happens when circle and rectangle collapses. There is also a problem that circle can go out of frame, which I don't know how to limit it's movement. I'm not even sure if it's possible to do what I want this way.This is supposed to be a game where I need to dodge all rectangles and this is best I could do. Thanks it advance :)

```
       public class Java2 extends Application {

       public static final int KRUG_WIDTH = 10; 
       public static final int PANEL_WIDTH = 600;
       public static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 600;

       private int mX = (PANEL_WIDTH - KRUG_WIDTH) / 2;
       private int mY = (PANEL_HEIGHT - KRUG_WIDTH) / 2;
       Random ran = new Random();

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {




            Rectangle rekt = new Rectangle(20, 20);
            Rectangle rekt1 = new Rectangle(20, 20);


            Circle r1 = new Circle(mX,mY,KRUG_WIDTH);  

            Pane root = new Pane(); //PANE

            r1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            r1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);

            root.getChildren().add(r1);
            root.getChildren().add(rekt);
            root.getChildren().add(rekt1);

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);





    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    Path path = new Path();



    //REKT-PATH
    pathTransition.setDuration(javafx.util.Duration.millis(600));
    pathTransition.setPath(path);
    pathTransition.setNode(rekt);
    pathTransition.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
    pathTransition.setCycleCount(2);
    pathTransition.setAutoReverse(true);
            pathTransition.setOnFinished(e -> {

                pathTransition.setPath(createPath());
                pathTransition.play();

            });
    pathTransition.play();




    PathTransition pathTransition1 = new PathTransition();
    Path path1 = new Path();



    //REKT1-PATH
    pathTransition1.setDuration(javafx.util.Duration.millis(550));
    pathTransition1.setPath(path1);
    pathTransition1.setNode(rekt1);
    pathTransition1.setOrientation(
PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
    pathTransition1.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    pathTransition1.setAutoReverse(true);
            pathTransition1.setOnFinished(e -> {

                pathTransition1.setPath(createPath());
                pathTransition1.play();

            });
    pathTransition1.play();





    r1.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
               switch (e.getCode()) {
                     case DOWN: r1.setCenterY(r1.getCenterY()+ 10);
                            break;
                     case UP: r1.setCenterY(r1.getCenterY()- 10);
                            break;
                     case LEFT: r1.setCenterX(r1.getCenterX() - 10);
                            break;
                     case RIGHT: r1.setCenterX(r1.getCenterX() + 10);
                            break;
                     case SPACE: 
                         break;

                     default:

               }
             });




            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            r1.requestFocus();
        }


    private Path createPath() {
            int loc2 = ran.nextInt(600 - 300 + 1) + 300;
            int loc = ran.nextInt(600 - 20 + 1) + 20; 

            Path path = new Path();

            path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(20, 20));
            path.getElements().add(new LineTo(loc, loc2));

            return path;

        }
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach isn't one I would take. Usually you have a timer as a game loop in which all the magic is happening, i. e. move sprites, check collision, update sprites in the UI. In JavaFX this would be an [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html).

In your code you miss several important things, among them the keyboard or mouse input. Or how you check the collision. There is e. g. an [intersects](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#intersects%28javafx.geometry.Bounds%29) method for the nodes, but that checks only the rectangular bounds of a node. You however have a circle, which makes matters more complex. However, if performance isn't an issue for your game, you could use the [Shape's intersect method](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#intersect%28javafx.scene.shape.Shape,%20javafx.scene.shape.Shape%29) to create a new shape out of Rectangle and Circle and depending on the result decide whether you have a collision or not.

Some time ago I created example code about [how to move sprites on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057870/in-javafx-how-do-i-move-a-sprite-across-the-screen/29058909) and check if they collide with others.

Regarding bouncing off the scene bounds in that code you simply check the scene bounds and change the movement delta to a bouncing value, i. e. if the sprite moves from left to right (dx is positive) and is at the right side, you set the delta dx to a negative value so that it moves in the opposite direction.

You can also take a look at a [simple Pong game](http://wecode4fun.blogspot.co.at/2015/05/simple-game-engine-pong.html) which uses a slightly modified version of that engine.

---

Example for shape intersection with your code:

```
Shape shape = Shape.intersect(rekt, r1);
boolean intersects = shape.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() != -1; 
if( intersects) {
  System.out.println( "Collision");
}
```

That alone raises the question where you'd put the check. Normally you'd have to perform it when anything moves, i. e. in both path transitions like this

```
pathTransition.currentTimeProperty().addListener( e -> {
...
});
```

and in the circle transition. That would be 2 checks too many.

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer , I will check up for animation timer and I will check up for that ping pong game . This will probably help me alot .